# append div class within jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
function Filter($container, params, markers) {
  var $label;
  this.markers = markers;
  this.values = {};
  this.key = params.key;
  $label = $('<label />').text(params.label);
  this.$element = $('<select class="form-control input-lg"/>');
  this.$element.append($('<option />').attr('value', 'all').text('All'));
  $container.append($label, this.$element);
}
```

Essentially, this renders.

```
<label>Category</label>
 <select class="form-control input-lg">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="Pizza">Pizza</option>
  <option value="Mexican">Mexican</option>
 </select>
```

But I want it to wrap the above with.

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-4">
 -- and --
</div>
```

ANy suggestions please, I have tried almost all variants with no success.

Comment: Have you tried using `.wrap('<div>')` on that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery Wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to wrap an element, but in your case I'd go for this:

```
var formgroup = $("<div class='form-group col-xs-4'/>");
formgroup.append($label, this.$element);
$container.append(formgroup);
```

Comment: check my edit, probably just append the `form-group` with label & select, and append `form-group` to `container`